# jquery footer, call footer.html from higher directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, footer

I can't seem to figure out why this wont work. I have a footer.html file in my main directory, one level above the directory this file is located in. I'm trying to include it on all the pages in the website, without having to have the footer.html file copied into every subdirectory. I assumed that a simple ../ preceding the footer.html would work, like it does in HTML, but maybe it doesn't work in jquery? It works fine on all the pages in the top level directory where the footer.html file is located. Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? It validates as correct. I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking. The whole point of making one footer.html page is so that I can update it in one place and it updates on every page, if I can't figure this out, it sort of defeats the purpose. Also: should I move the script to the head tag instead of nesting it inside the footer div tag?

HEADER:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <title></title>
 <style>
  body {background-color:#000000; color:#ffbb00;}
  a, h1 {color:#ffffff;}
  .center-div {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 1084px!important;
   background-color:#000000;}
  div.rule { margin: 0 auto;
   width:50%; 
   height:1px; 
   background:#ffbb00; 
   align:center; 
   overflow:hidden;}
 </style>
</head>
```

FOOTER:

```
<div id="footer">
 <script>
 $( "#footer" ).load( "../footer.html" );
 </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting a `404` in console? And in regards to putting the script somewhere else, personally I'd say move it to the `<head>`. As it stands now, your code will be deleting itself, which is somewhat strange IMHO. If your `footer.html` is at the *root* level of your site, you could also just do `.load("/footer.html");`

Comment: Post the folder structure you have (*and where are the html files and where the footer file*)

Comment: http://phaewryn.net/WebDevMirror/im/directories.JPG

Comment: @Santi .load("/footer.html"); does not work. I tried that first. Neither does footer.html without the /.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli http://phaewryn.net/WebDevMirror/im/directories.JPG is the best I can do, the server doesn't allow FTP, and my only access is through this weird file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing metaphores here.

jQuery's .load uses a URL which doesn't conform with file-system methods. You'll need to either use the absolute reference to the URL of the footer or use some javascript to figure out what it is. For example:

```
window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1)+"footer.html"
```

That's pretty goofy, but it finds the last "/" in your URL then cuts everything after it and appends footer.html to it.

Comment: I edited the page to reflect the full URL of the address the footer.html page is located at, and it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure? If you put http://sitename.edu/footer.html do you see your footer? I suspect your URL is incorrect.

Comment: I thought I was sure, but I uploaded the page one more time after checking everything, and suddenly, the footer has appeared. I must have not been uploading the edited version or something. Can you verify that you can see the footer on this webpage now? 
http://jdo09280.classweb.ccv.edu/Assignment01/research.html

Comment: If it's the webmaster... etc that comes below the orange line then yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is inside the block it's trying to look up, it's probably not loaded yet. Best practice is to wrap jquery calls in a `$(document).ready()`. Also, it's cleaner to not use relative stuff in your url's like `../`. If you use relative paths that start with a slash like `/templates/footer.html`, you can reuse the same script on all your pages.

Comment: But it works fine that way in the main directory. See: http://jdo09280.classweb.ccv.edu/

Comment: Can you show me how to correctly wrap that around my code? I know basically nothing about jquery/javascript, I would have previously used server side includes or iframes for this purpose, but those are not options on this server/for this class, which has to be in validating HTML5.

Comment: I now have this in the head, is this correct?
    `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
      $( "#footer" ).load( "footer.html" );
 });
    </script>`

Comment: Yeah, that looks ok, although that's an old verison of jquery. Should still work though.

Comment: What is the current url for the current version I should be using? Where do I find that, for future reference? I just copied this code from a google search result answer to someone else asking a question (you know how that goes), so I don't know where to find the info myself. I strive to keep my pages as up to date as possible, so if there's a newer version, I'd love to know how I can find out when those are released.

Comment: Sure, if you look on the jquery website, they've got the newest version listed. Here's their CDN page: https://code.jquery.com/